# Present date verification in Robotium Script

Tags: java, android, automation, robotium

I need a help regarding robotium script.My scenario is like "In my AUT present date is available "30 january 2014". So i need to verify whether its current date or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can either parse that `String` to a `Date` and compare it with today or you can format today's date to a `String` and check it with the available date. Here is an example of how you can achieve it using the latter logic.

```
String day = "30 january 2014"; // Available Date
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy"); // DateFormat matching your available date
if (df.format(new Date()).equalsIgnoreCase(day)) { // check for equality, ignoring the case
    // It is today's date if the control comes here.
} else {
    // It is not today's date if the control comes here.
}
```